# Exclude a specific match in SQL

Tags: sql

Good Morning
I am fairly new to the world of SQL, and stuck on an issue. I have been searching forums but not really found an answer.
I have 2 tables
**Incidents**, which holds all the information for an IT Incident and
**Employee**, which holds all the Employee information.
The Incident table has the Name of the person who resolved the Incident, but not the team they work in.
I have created a join, as both tables have the UserID and I am trying to bring back the Team from the Employee table, however several of the Employees have 2 entries, one is the correct team and the other is "Self Service".
My question is, is there a way to always ignore any match of "Self Service", and just use the other record?
Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks

Apologies, I'm using SSMS v14
The code I have so far is

```
SELECT 
    i.CreatedBy, 
    COALESCE (e.Team, e1.Team) as CreatedByTeam, 
    i.CreatedDateTime, 
    i.Owner, 
    i.OwnerTeam, 
    i.LastModDateTime, 
    i.ResolvedBy,
    COALESCE (e2.Team, e3.Team) as ResolvedByTeam
FROM 
    Incident i
    LEFT JOIN Employee e ON i.CreatedBy=e.DisplayName
    LEFT JOIN Employee e1 ON i.CreatedBy=e1.PrimaryEmail
    LEFT JOIN Employee e2 ON i.ResolvedBy=e2.DisplayName
    LEFT JOIN Employee e3 ON i.ResolvedBy=e3.PrimaryEmail
WHERE 
    i.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2021-06-09' AND '2022-06-09' OR i.LastModDateTime BETWEEN '2021-06-09' AND '2022-06-09'
```

And it is the 2 COALESCEs that are returning the Self Service results

Comment: Hi, please can you share with us what database you use ? Also, please share with us the code you have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your current SQL statement? You can probably include something like: `TEAM <> 'Self Service'` in your `ON` statement

Comment: What is the deciding point to exclude this team? If it is really just the name, do something like Vvdl proposed. If the team has a specific flag or id which will never change, it could be better to check this condition since the name could change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the Self Service records using a `WHERE` statement, preferrably only doing it once using a cte:

```
WITH pure_employee AS (
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Team <> 'Self Service'
)

SELECT 
    i.CreatedBy, 
    COALESCE (e.Team, e1.Team) as CreatedByTeam, 
    i.CreatedDateTime, 
    i.Owner, 
    i.OwnerTeam, 
    i.LastModDateTime, 
    i.ResolvedBy,
    COALESCE (e2.Team, e3.Team) as ResolvedByTeam
FROM 
    Incident i
    LEFT JOIN pure_employee e ON i.CreatedBy=e.DisplayName
    LEFT JOIN pure_employee e1 ON i.CreatedBy=e1.PrimaryEmail
    LEFT JOIN pure_employee e2 ON i.ResolvedBy=e2.DisplayName
    LEFT JOIN pure_employee e3 ON i.ResolvedBy=e3.PrimaryEmail
WHERE 
    i.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2021-06-09' AND '2022-06-09' OR i.LastModDateTime BETWEEN '2021-06-09' AND '2022-06-09'
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work really well, never used a cte before